# What is the limit to encoding base in case of Unicode strings as opposed to base64 having base = 64?

Tags: unicode, encoding, language-agnostic

This is actually related to code golf in general, but also appliable elsewhere. **People commonly use base64 encoding to store large amounts of binary data in source code**.

Assuming all programming languages to be happy to read Unicode source code, **what is the max N, for which we can reliably devise a baseN encoding**?

Reliability here means being able to encode/decode any data, so every single combination of input bytes can be encoded, and then decoded. The encoded form is free from this rule.

The main goal is **to minimize the character count, regardless of byte-count**.

**Would it be base2147483647 (32-bit) ?**

Also, because I know it may vary from browser-to-browser, and we already have problems with copy-pasting code from codegolf answers to our editors, the copy-paste-ability is also a factor here. I know there is a Unicode range of characters that are not displayed.

NOTE:
I know that for binary data, base64 usually expands data, but here the character-count is the main factor.

Comment: I know that for binary data, base64 usually expands data, but here the character-count is the main factor.

Comment: "*People commonly use base64 encoding to store large amounts of data in a compact form*" - no they don't. Base64 **increases** the size of the encoded data by 4/3.  Base64 is commonly used where binary data is not allowed but printable ASCII characters are allowed.

Comment: Sorry, it was late. Edited. Also note the NOTE and my comment.

Comment: How would encoding your payload in Unicode be an improvement over simply storing it as a binary?  You can hardly get more than one byte per byte anyway. The main issue either way is how to keep the payload from being mixed with your program data, which is more or less the only problem which a less efficient encoding solves elegantly.  If you want to allow free-form Unicode, how do you encode a payload which contains whichever sequence would otherwise be seen as the payload terminator?

Comment: @tripleee I certainly didn't see the terminator issue coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on how *reliable* you want the encoding to be. Character encodings are designed with trade-offs, and in general the more characters allowed, the less likely it is to be universally accepted i.e. less reliable. Base64 isn't immune to this. [RFC 3548](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548), published in 2003, mentions that case sensitivity may be an issue, and that the characters `+` and `/` may be problematic in certain scenarios. It describes Base32 (no lowercase) and Base16 (hex digits) as potentially safer alternatives.

It does not get better with Unicode. Adding that many characters introduces many more possible points of failure. Depending on how stringent your requirements are, you might have different values for *N*. I'll cover a few possibilities from large *N* to small *N*, adding a requirement each time.

- 1,114,112: **Code points**. This is the number of possible code points defined by the Unicode Standard.
- 1,112,064: **Valid [UTF](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)**. This excludes the surrogates which cannot stand on their own.
- 1,111,998: **Valid for exchange between processes**. Unicode reserves 66 code points as permanent [non-characters](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html) for internal use only. Theoretically, this is the maximum *N* you could justifiably expect for your copy-paste scenario, but as you noted, in practice many other Unicode strings will fail that exercise.
- 120,503: **Printable characters only**, depending on your definition. I've defined it to be all characters outside of the *Other* and *Separator* [general categories](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm). Also, starting from this bullet point, *N* is subject to change in future versions of Unicode.
- 103,595: **NFKD normalized Unicode**. Unfortunately, many processes automatically [normalize Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/faq/normalization.html) input to a standardized form. If the process used NFKC or NFKD, some information may have been lost. For more reliability, the encoding should thus define a normalization form, with NFKD being better for increasing character count
- 101,684: **No [combining characters](http://www.unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html)**. These are "characters" which shouldn't stand on their own, such as accents, and are meant to be combined with another base character. Some processes might panic if they are left standing alone, or if there are too many combining characters on a single base character. I've now excluded the *Mark* category.
- 85: **[ASCII85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85)**, aka. I want my ASCII back. Okay, this is no longer Unicode, but I felt like mentioning it because it's a lesser known ASCII-only encoding. It's mainly used in Adobe's PostScript and PDF formats, and has a 5:4 encoded data size increase, rather than Base64's 4:3 ratio.

Comment: I will wait until a week from the original posting before I accept your answer, but yours is a great candidate so far. Also, references are most welcome. Thank you for your input! :)